# Recognizing strings composed only by numbers

Tags: python, string, numbers

I was trying to code a function able to concatenate two words and multiply two floats, but I'm having issues with the try-error module. I want the function to also check whether the str are just composed of numbers or not, but this is not working. Could you find the problem?

```
def funz():
    w1=input('insert a word')
    w2=input('insert a second word')
    n1=input('insert a num')
    n2=input('insert a second num')
    try:
        float(w2), float(w1)
        print('I want a word')
        funz()
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float(n2), float(n1)

            print('\n')
            print(w1+w2)
            print('\n')
            print(float(n1)*float(n2))
        except ValueError:
            print('I said a number!')
            funz()
funz()
```

Comment: don't use recursion to retry an operation. Use a loop with break.

Comment: do not recurse into the same function - you are stacking callframes . Use a while() loop

Comment: "insert a word" then you convert this word to float. Unclear for the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the `try` statement:

```
try:
    float(w2), float(w1)
    print('I want a word')
    funz()
```

Note that with this statement, you only check if one of the two words are not `float`. As soon as either `w1` or `w2` cannot be turned into a `float`, meaning that it is a word, you jump to the `except` statement. Which is wrong as one of them might be numeric.

By the way here's a cleaner and much simpler way to do the same:

```
def funz():

    while True:

        w1=input('insert a word')
        w2=input('insert a second word')
        n1=input('insert a num')
        n2=input('insert a second num')

        if not (str(w1).isalpha()) & str(w2).isalpha():
            print('I want a word')
            continue

        if not (str(n1).isnumeric()) & (str(n2).isnumeric()):
            print('I said a number!')
            continue

        print('\n'+w1+w2+'\n')
        print(float(n1)*float(n2))
        break
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your suggestion, it was very clear.

Answer (score 1):

**isalpha** will help you:

```
if w1.isalpha() and w2.isapha():
    # w1 and w2 have not any numeric values
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried .isalpha(), but it seems like it only detects the punctuation, and not the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this small example helps:

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Please type something: ")
    try:
        user_input = float(user_input)
        print("Your input can be interpreted as a float")
    except:
        print("Your input can *not* be interpreted as a float")
        continue
    break
```

This will assure that `user_input` is a `float` - otherwise the loop would have started over once again because of `continue`.

If you want to assure that `user_input` is **not** a `float`, just move the `continue`:

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Please type something: ")
    try:
        user_input = float(user_input)
        print("Your input can be interpreted as a float")
        continue
    except:
        print("Your input can *not* be interpreted as a float")
    break
```